# Pyinstaller : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, opencv

**i can't use cv2 with pyinstaller**
this is the complete error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1601, in <module>
    KeyAuth().run()
  File "main.py", line 103, in run
    Visual().main_menu()
  File "main.py", line 1595, in main_menu
    options().option(ops)
  File "main.py", line 1395, in option
    CaptchaOBJ = Captcha()
  File "main.py", line 1001, in __init__
    self.solver = CaptchaSolver('captcha.pt')
  File "main.py", line 893, in __init__
    self.model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='models/'+model, force_reload=True)
  File "torch\hub.py", line 540, in load
  File "torch\hub.py", line 569, in _load_local
  File "C:\Users\loren/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 83, in custom
    return _create(path, autoshape=autoshape, verbose=_verbose, device=device)
  File "C:\Users\loren/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 33, in _create
    from models.common import AutoShape, DetectMultiBackend
  File "C:\Users\loren/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\common.py", line 18, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

[14932] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!

i tried to add cv2 with command **'--hidden-imports=opencv-python'** or **'--hidden-imports=cv2'** but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you probably have pyinstaller installed into a different environment than where cv2 is installed